# Force permissions on directory for Netatalk

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm working on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I'm trying to set up an AFP share with **Netatalk**. So far so good aside from the privileges to the files inside the shared directories.

I want to set up a system that whenever a user creates or places a file in a certain directory it will automatically provide 770 and set a specific group as the owning group of the directory.

I've got the owning group part working fine by using: `chmod g+s /directory`

The part that I can't seem to get working is the permissions for the files created inside the directory.

I've read a bit about ACL and setting a default ACL, and I've tried a few things regarding that with no luck. I tried the following:

```
setfacl -m "default:group::rwx" /directory
mount -o remount,acl /mountPoint
```

I also added acl to the `/etc/fstab` for the correct drive however I have not rebooted the machine yet as it is a server I'd rather not have to take down and I thought the `mount -o remount,acl /mountPoint` would do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

From this [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2070746)

Edited `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default` so it reads:

```
# The line below sets some DEFAULT, starting with Netatalk 2.1.
:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots

# By default all users have access to their home directories.
~/          "Home Directory"
/srv/files/Agentur  "Agentur"       allow:@mitarbeiter dperm:0770 fperm:0660 umask:0007
/srv/files/Test     "Test"          allow:@mitarbeiter dperm:0750 fperm:0660 umask:0007
```